# Inject dependency for singleton objective c class in swift test cases

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, design-patterns

I have one singleton class written in Objective C which is being used in helper class which is also written in Objective C. I am writing a test case for the helper class, but instead of making changes directly to singleton class methods, I want to create a mock singleton class, but I'm not sure how to do that. I don't want to make any changes in helper class either like creating a init method which takes singleton class object and initialise it like mention on other threads for test cases for singleton class.

Thanks for looking the question.

Comment: You say, "I don't want to make any changes in helper class".  I am not an expert in this but I think you're making your job harder than necessary with that restriction.

Comment: I mean this would be my last solution but i am looking if there is any better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OCMock for mocking objects in your project [OCMock](https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock)

Then you can mock your singleton like this

```
YOUR_SINGLETON *mock = OCMClassMock([YOUR_SINGLETON class]);
```

And stub function like this

```
OCMStub([(id) mock YOUR_FUNCTION:PARAMETER]).andReturn(VALUE_FOR_TEST_CASE);
```

Comment: Thanks but not looking for any third party solution.